# PHP - Build multiple-level HTML menu from php array combining like values based on value name

Tags: php, html, arrays, menu, nested

I have searched a bit on SO and haven't been able to find this unique use case, but maybe I don't know how to phrase it.  I am looking to use a PHP array (see format below) to build a dynamic HTML menu that duplicates identical string values into sub menus when a match exists.

This may be too complicated but I would like to find out if it is possible and if someone has a code sample.  **I don't mind changing the 'verse' array value structure to make it more mutable** and get this to work (perhaps turning it into array since there are 1:many potential values in it.)

I could not get the HTML below to format quite right for SO but the gist of the request is that all articles with a matching book/chapter string would get placed together and nested.  If there are 2 entries for Psalms 121 (which there are in the below array), then they should be nested together in the same sub-menu.

Desired End Structure (Note that because 2 strings matched Psalms chapter 121, they were combined together:

```
Hebrews
    Chapter 12
        Verse 26-28
    Chapter 9
        Verse 23-24

Psalms
    Chapter 121
         Verse 3-4
         Verse 7-10
    Chapter 16
         Verse 11

Exodus
    Chapter 33
         Verse 14
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

PHP Array:

```
<?php

$articles = array(

array(
    'contentid' => '109',
    'full' => 'Song by Artist (Ref 109)',
    'verse' => 'Hebrews 12:26-28'),

array(
    'contentid' => '110',
    'full' => 'Song by Artist (Ref 110)',
    'verse' => 'Psalms 121:3-4'),

array(
    'contentid' => '111',
    'full' => 'Song by Artist (Ref 111)',
    'verse' => 'Hebrews 9:23-24'),

array(
    'contentid' => '112',
    'full' => 'Song by Artist (Ref 112)',
    'verse' => 'Psalms 16:11; Exodus 33:14; Psalms 121:7-10'));

?>
```

I would like this to draw an HTML menu that looks like this:

```
<!-- Hebrews -->
                    <div class="submenu">
                        <a href="#">**Hebrews**</a>
                        <!-- Level 2 menu -->
                        <div>
                            <div>


                                <div class="submenu">
                                    <a href="#">Chapter *12*</a>
                                    <!-- Level 3 menu -->
                                    <div>
                                        <div>
                                            <a href="#"><span>Song by Artist (Ref 109)</span>Verse *26-28*</a>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="submenu">
                                    <a href="#">Chapter *9*</a>
                                    <!-- Level 3 menu -->
                                    <div>
                                        <div>
                                            <a href="#"><span>Song by Artist (Ref 111)</span>Verse *23-24*</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

<!-- Psalms -->

                    <div class="submenu">
                        <a href="#">**Psalms**</a>
                        <!-- Level 2 menu -->
                        <div>
                            <div>

                                <div class="submenu">
                                    <a href="#">Chapter *121*</a>
                                    <!-- Level 3 menu -->
                                    <div>
                                        <div>
                                            <a href="#"><span>Song by Artist (Ref 110)</span>Verse *3-4*</a>
                                            <a href="#"><span>Song by Artist (Ref 112)</span>Verse *7-10*</a>                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Chapter *9*


        
                                                                               
            Song by Artist (Ref 111)Verse *23-24*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$articles = array
(
    array
    (
        'contentid' => '109',
        'full' => 'Song by Artist (Ref 109)',
        'verse' => 'Hebrews 12:26-28'
    ),

    array
    (
        'contentid' => '110',
        'full' => 'Song by Artist (Ref 110)',
        'verse' => 'Psalms 121:3-4'
    ),

    array
    (
        'contentid' => '111',
        'full' => 'Song by Artist (Ref 111)',
        'verse' => 'Hebrews 9:23-24; Psalms 121:3-4'
    ),

    array
    (
        'contentid' => '112',
        'full' => 'Song by Artist (Ref 112)',
        'verse' => 'Psalms 16:11; Exodus 33:14; Psalms 121:7-10; Psalms 121:3-4'
    )
);



$langs = array();

foreach($articles as $article)
{
    foreach(explode("; ", $article["verse"]) as $verseData)
    {
        $verse = explode(" ", $verseData);
        $lang = $verse[0];
        $fullVerse = $verse[1];
        $verse = explode(":", $verse[1]);
        $chapter = $verse[0];

        if(empty($langs[$lang]))
            $langs[$lang] = array();

        if(empty($langs[$lang][$fullVerse]))
            $langs[$lang][$fullVerse] = array();

        $langs[$lang][$fullVerse][] = array
        (
            "full" => $article["full"]
        );
    }
}

foreach($langs as $lang => $data)
{
    generateHtml($lang, $data);
}

function generateHtml($lang, $data)
{
    echo "<!-- ". $lang ." -->\n";
    echo "<div class=\"submenu\">\n";
    echo "<a href=\"#\">**". $lang ."**</a>\n";
    echo "<!-- Level 2 menu -->\n";
    echo "<div>\n";
    echo "<div>\n";

    foreach($data as $fullVerse => $verses)
    {
        $verse = explode(":", $fullVerse);
        $chapter = $verse[0];
        $verse = $verse[1];

        echo "<div class=\"submenu\">\n";
        echo "<a href=\"#\">Chapter *". $chapter ."*</a>\n";
        echo "<!-- Level 3 menu -->\n";
        echo "<div>\n";
        echo "<div>\n";

        foreach($verses as $verseIndex => $value)
        {
            if(count($verses) > 1)
                $value["full"] .= " (". ($verseIndex + 1) .")";

            echo "<a href=\"#\"><span>". $value["full"] ."</span>Verse *". $verse ."*</a>\n";
        }

        echo "</div>\n";
        echo "</div>\n";
    }

    echo "</div>\n";
    echo "</div>\n";
    echo "</div>\n";
}
```

You can use `\t` to also add the tab space.
My suggestion is if you already generating it like this. make it one line by removing all the `\n`.

Comment: I'll try this soon, thank you!!  So this will take into account matching books, chapters and verses and put them together as described?  Really appreciate it!

Comment: this is wonderful--thanks so much for your time.  One quick thing, I was hoping that it would write multiple entries for the same article as well.  So for example, contentID 112 should have one verse entry written in Psalms 16, one in Exodus 33, and one in Psalms 121.  Note that ID 110 is also writing to the Psalms 121 chapter code block.   To illustrate this simply, Exodus (in contentid 112) is not being written out in my tests (because the code seems only to be reading the 1st entry (Psalms 16) and not the subsequent semicolon separated list.   Can you help me tune this just a little?

Comment: Tested with multiple matches for Psalms 121 but I don't think it is nesting properly.   The code above is writing out two seperate entries for Psalms 121, each with its own verse.  The resulting HTML is properly formatted, etc. but the goal is to have it write out only 1 entry for Chapter 121, with 2 verse entries (one for verses 3-4 & one for verses 7-10).   Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: thanks for your ongoing help!  This is *very* close to what I am aiming for!  I just need to make sure that both Psalms 121 entries get nested together.   So, the end structure becomes:

LVL 1) Psalms
     -> LVL 2) Chapter 121
            -> LVL 3) Verse 3-4
            -> LVL 3) Verse 7-10

**I am adding the desired end tree structure, so to speak, to the initial question to make it clear.**

This is so close and I will mark your answer correct in a bit regardless cause you've been so helpful.  Can you help me over this last hurtle if you can find the time?  Thanks either way in advance!

Comment: Sure, no problem. answer edited. I should of noticed it in the begging .. ;D my bad :)

Comment: You are amazing, I had no idea this wAs possible.! I want to become a PHP guru now... Thanks!!  I have multiple comtentIDS that refer to the same exact book/chapter/verse.  Is it possible to display all of these (allow duplicates).  Although the menu will say "Verse 4-6" (two or even more times), the hover over the link will show what the link points towards.  Thank you so much and I understand if you cannot spend anymore time on this.  You have been so helpful and have inspired me!!

Comment: Can you explain better what you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Sure.  Right now, everything is working as described except when I have different content IDs that point to the same 'verse' value--like I have 4 articles that all point to precisely Matthew 2:17-18.  I need all 4 hits to appear in Matthew -> Chapter 2 -> Verse 17-18.   They will appear to be duplicated in the user menu but that is fine because the rollover for each will show the 'full' value which is a unique description.  I would like duplicate verses to be shown).  Appears messy to not strip to be unique but I'm going somewhere with it :). Thanks again!!

Comment: It would be even more amazing if the code could append a string '(1)', '(2)', '(3)', '(4)', etc. after the verse e.g., "Verse 17-18 (2)" --- Of course, this should only happen when more than 1 Identical verse is found.  I know I'm "using you" at this point--sorry!  That is totally optional but would be killer if it's easy.  Thanks again for all your time!!

Comment: I edited the answer, let me know if this is what you wanted. I did in in a rush at morning ;D

Comment: I am in love.  This was so simple and this is EXACTLY what I needed.  Thank you so much for your time @Ido and being willing to go back and modify this for me even though I expanded scope on you.  Really, REALLY appreciate it.  +1000.  I will formalize it tomorrow into my menu as opposed to just html raw text output but it is doing exactly what I need!!!  Marked as correct answer!!!

Comment: Glad you help, for the next time try to do it by yourself. this is the best way of learning. take it slowly when you do, don't try to make the whole thing. just small parts.

Comment: I got so excited about the lv3 entries (verses) not being duplicated that I didn't notice lvl2 (chapters) is getting the same treatment.  I am trying to have all matching chapter references nested together so there should only be one chapter written (duplication allowed), but multiple verse.   Here is a link to describe what I mean:  http://img42.com/xg4DP+    -- I know you probably want me to try to figure this out myself :) but I have a baby on the way really soon and I'm trying to get this project off before!  If this isn't a big code re-write, could you help me out just 1 last time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77565/discussion-between-kurt-w-and-ido).

Comment: can we chat sometime in the next few days to mirror what is in the screenshot I posted in the prior comment by chance?  Thanks either way in advance!

Comment: I spent quite a few hours looking this over and ended up with a revision of the code based on your third revision.  I ended up just making all the verses unique by appending A, B, C, etc. for duplicates so chapters are being nested and verses are where I want them to be.  Thanks for your patience with me... just remarked the answer as correct.